Structure of Dimeric Beryllium Chloride
In the vapour phase, beryllium chloride exists in its dimeric state, wherein one beryllium atom is bound to two chlorine atoms via covalent bonds and to one chlorine atom via a coordinate bond with chlorine as the donor atom.
Beryllium is sp2 hybridized here; it has two sp2 orbitals taking part in covalent bond formation and has a vacant sp2 and a vacant 2p orbital left with it. My question here is, do we consider that the lone pair donated by the chlorine atom enters the vacant 2p orbital, or the vacant sp2 orbital of beryllium?


Consider that: 1) Both bonds of bridging Cl are identical. 2) Would you think there's pi bond without sigma? And you should be able to tell which one is it.

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/154332/does-becl2n-have-3-center-4-electron-bonding-or-not

"Would you think there's pi bond without sigma?" Yes, that is how there is homoaromaticity. But in this case, as in most, you need the sigma bonding first.
